# undefined method grouped_options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Anyone have any idea why the following code is resulting in an "undefined method `'grouped_options_for_select'` for `#<ActionView::Base:0x43881ec>`" error?

```
@user_options = [['Group 1',['User 1','User 2']],['Group 2',['User 3','User 4']]]
select_tag('ufc[proponent]',grouped_options_for_select(@user_options))
```

I'm about to pull my hair out, so it must be something obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. the `grouped_options_for_select` helper wasn't added to ActionView until Rails 2.3. I'm working with Rails 2.1.

Knew it had to be something simple!